# Why the Swiftmailer in Yii2 does not work and IP in blacklist?

Tags: php, yii2, swiftmailer

The email was worked, but now it is crash because IP is blacklisted.
How to resolve this problem?

When I send email using Swiftmailer this error I see

> Expected response code 220 but got code "550", with the message
>   "550-Message rejected because [50.87.249.98]:20423 is blacklisted see
>   Blocked - 550 Too many failed logins "

[image]

This code in `conmmon/config/main-local.php`

```
'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'transport' => [
            'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'host' => 'box1298.bluehost.com',
            'username' => 'test@domain.co', // my email
            'password' => '**************', // password
            'port' => 465,
            'encryption' => 'ssl',
            'streamOptions' => [
                'ssl' => [
                    'allow_self_signed' => true,
                    'verify_peer' => false,
                    'verify_peer_name' => false,
                ],
            ]
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: Have you read the error message? What is unclear from that message?

Comment: looks like the password has been changed and the failed attempt has raisen the warning it has nothing to do with code

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with your code. If your SMTP server blocks your IP you should contact with your hosting provider and ask about unblocking this IP. Or wait - such blocks are usually temporary.

But in your case it looks like your server blocked itself, so I suggest to contact with hosting support to explain the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Shameless plug: you can use a [free email API like Flute Mail](https://www.flutemail.com) which automatically circumvents temporary blacklists. How it works: you can setup multiple email servers or providers on your Flute account, and it will resend your email through a different provider if it detects an error like this.

It's completely free for small volume senders, so all you need to do is change your code to forward requests through your Virtual Flute (and then pop replace your SMTP credentials). The Virtual Flute will need to be be configured to send through your SMTP server (or other free email APIs like Mailgun).

Let me know if you have any questions about Flute (I built it).